# ASP.NET Identity - Re-authenticate on some areas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm starting a new project using ASP.NET Identity 2.1.

In my app, I will use the remember me feature, so, I have a question.

How can I force users to re-authenticate when they access certain pages (for ex, Admin area) if they were authenticated by the «remember me» feature?

For ex, an admin forgets to logout. 
A few hours later, someone uses his browser, and is logged in our app by the remember me feature.

There is no problem for me, if that person can navigate our app being logged as Admin, but I don't want that person to access the admin, or some sensitive areas of my app without being forced to login again.

Does anyone know how to do this, or if the framework has something similar ready to use?

Thanks

Comment: You can use a claim where you have a privy timestamp.  When the user navigates to the admin page, check that claim and if it is expired, say 10 minutes, then have a popup or redirect them to a special log in page where you reset that privy claim.

Comment: That's a nice use of Claims :D I'll try that 

Thanks